# Node.JS Azure MySQL { [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false }

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, timeout

I have app which connects to free Azure MySQL service and make queries in a loop. I use single connection to make those queries (I am limited to 4 connections), and process takes usually ~5 seconds. When I run app locally, it works perfectly fine, but after deployment do azure I get

```
{ [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false }
```

In my logs. How can I prevent this, and why does it work correctly locally, but not on Azure?

Comment: Do you have 'express-sql-session' or 'express-mysql-session' in your proeject? Try to remove it and deploy to azure again.

Comment: i just have MysQL (it's MysQL database)

Comment: Here is my code snippet, I do not use Express, it's plain node.js application: http://pastebin.com/j0wZqm7P

Answer (score 0):

There was an answered SO thread as the same issue as yours, you can refer to [Node JS Mysql PROTOCOL ENQUEUE AFTER FATAL ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549193/node-js-mysql-protocol-enqueue-after-fatal-error) and try to solve the issue.