# localhost:8800/api/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error) when trying to register a new user

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to create a website with register/login/logout functions using react and mysql, right now I'm kinda stuck in the registration part. When trying to create a new user I'm getting this error:

```
p://localhost:8800/api/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

If I try to write localhost:8800/api/auth/register in url bar this is what I find in the screen:  `Cannot GET /api/auth/register`

This is the code I'm using:

server/index.js

```
import express from "express";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js"
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"
import cors from "cors"


const app = express()

// middlewares
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);


app.listen(8800, () => {
    console.log("API working!");
  });
```

server/connect.js

```
import mysql from "mysql"

export const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host:"localhost",
  user:"root",
  password:"password",
  database:"auth"
})
```

server/routes/auth.js

```
import express from "express";
import { login,register,logout } from "../controllers/auth.js";

const router = express.Router()

router.post("/register", register)
router.post("/login", login)
router.post("/logout", logout)


export default router
```

server/controllers/auth.js

```
import { db } from "../connect.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const register = (req, res) => {
  //CHECK USER IF EXISTS

  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length) return res.status(409).json("User already exists!");
    //CREATE A NEW USER
    //Hash the password
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    const q =
      "INSERT INTO users (`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUE (?)";

    const values = [
      req.body.username,
      req.body.email,
      hashedPassword,
    ];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
      return res.status(200).json("User has been created.");
    });
  });
};

export const login = (req, res) => {
  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length === 0) return res.status(404).json("User not found!");

    const checkPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(
      req.body.password,
      data[0].password
    );

    if (!checkPassword)
      return res.status(400).json("Wrong password or username!");

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: data[0].id }, "secretkey");

    const { password, ...others } = data[0];

    res
      .cookie("accessToken", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(others);
  });
};

export const logout = (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("accessToken",{
    secure:true,
    sameSite:"none"
  }).status(200).json("User has been logged out.")
};
```

src/pages/Register.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./register.scss";
import axios from "axios"

const Register = () => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        username:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
    })

    const [err, setErr] = useState(null)


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
      };

    const handleClick = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/api/auth/register", inputs)
        } catch(err) {
            setErr(err.response.data)
        }
    }
    console.log(inputs)


  return (
    <div className='register'>
        <div className="card">
            <div className="left">
                <h1>test-II</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.</p>
                <span>Hai già un account?</span>
                <Link to="/login">
                    <button>Login</button>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="right">
                <h1>Registrazione</h1>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder='Username' name="username" onChange={handleChange} />
                    <input type="email" placeholder='Email' name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
                    <input type="password" placeholder='Password' name="password" onChange={handleChange} />
                    {/* <p>{err && err}</p> */}
                    <button onClick={handleClick}>Registrati</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: possible to get the log?

Comment: This is the only thing I find printed in my console in terms of errors: 
`POST http://localhost:8800/api/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: can you `console.log(err.message)` in here

`if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);` btw, you can't call it from browser. Because, your route is POST. Not GET. If you're not sure, use postman to check more details

Comment: Thanks! this is the error printed in the console: ` {code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false}`

Answer (score 0):

The query is incorrect. It should be `VALUES` and there should be three `?` as you are inserting values for three columns.

Also, note that you don't need `[values]` just `values` is enough for the `.query()`'s parameter.

```
const q = "INSERT INTO users (`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

const values = [
    req.body.username,
    req.body.email,
    hashedPassword,
];

db.query(q, values, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    return res.status(200).json("User has been created.");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the important corrections, I've just started learning mysql! Unfortunly I'm still getting the 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Can you `console.log(err)` and share the error output

Comment: I've tried this: `if (err) return res.status(500).json(err), console.log(err);` but it's not printing anything

Comment: Not in the server side.. In your `.jsx`.. Instead of `console.log(inputs)` output `console.log(err)`

Comment: Thanks! this is what I'm getting: ` {code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false}`

Comment: Looks like that's MySQL connection issue. You can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74428717/11566161

Comment: @PisaPonente Did you solve your issues? Did you get past it? I'm having very similar problems.